# JavaScript Object of Array

Tags: javascript

I'm following the freeCodeCamp tutorial (https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/data-structures/create-a-set-class) to **create** a set. I'm confused by the dictionary property & **building** the class (*not* instantiating it but thank you for the replies). Is it an array? Is it an object without key value pairs? The example they gave makes it seem that way for my second question:

```
const set1 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 0]);
console.log(set1); // output: {1, 2, 3, 5, 0}
```

When I treat it like an array, it doesn't work. So how do I create an **add** or **remove** method to class Set?

```
class Set {
    constructor() {
        // Dictionary will hold the items of our set
        this.dictionary = {};
        this.length = 0;
    }
    add(element){

        dictionary.push(element) // fails
    }
    remove(element){
        if(dictionary.indexOf(element) === -1) // fails

    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the body of the `if`.

Comment: `dictionary` is not the same as `this.dictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dictionary` should be `this.dictionary`.

`{}` creates an object. Objects don't have `push()` or `indexOf()` methods. To add a new element to an object, assign to a property name. There's no need to test if the element is in the object when removing, just use `delete` to remove the element; if the key doesn't exist, it won't do anything.

You can use an object to represent a set by using the object keys as the set elements, since keys can't be duplicated. The value can be anything, it's ignored, because we're only using the keys.

If you do want to test whether a key exists, you can use `if (this.dictionary.hasOwnProperty(element))`

```js
class MySet {
  constructor() {
    // Dictionary will hold the items of our set
    this.dictionary = {};
  }
  add(element) {
    this.dictionary[element] = null;
  }
  remove(element) {
    delete this.dictionary[element];
  }
  get length() {
    return Object.keys(this.dictionary).length;
  }
}

let s = new MySet();
s.add("foo");
s.add("bar");
console.log(Object.keys(s.dictionary));
s.remove("foo");
console.log(Object.keys(s.dictionary));
```

Comment: I've added some more explanation. The value is irrelevant, we only care about the keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an array. Set is an object that holds unique values it has methods like has and add

```
const set1 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 0]); 
set1.has(2)// returns true
set1.delete(1) // removes the value 1
set1.add(33) // adds the value 33 at the end of the set
```

you can loop over it in sevral ways on of them using forEach

```
set1.forEach( value => console.log(value) )
```

Comment: My question was: So how do I create an add or remove method to class Set?

Comment: The set object has build-in methods, the add method can be used without the need to create it 
you can just do set1.delete(value) to remove or set1.add(value) to add new value to the set

Answer (score 0):

adding elements to a set can be easily achived by `add` method
below is a sample code
to delete an element you can use `delete` method

```js
var set = new Set();  
set.add("one");  
set.add("two");  
set.add("three");  
document.writeln("Size before invoking delete() method: "+ set.size+"<br>");  
set.delete("three");  
document.writeln("Size after invoking delete() method: "+set.size);
```

Comment: My question was: So how do I create an add or remove method to class Set?